# Xamarin Forms group controls without modifying layout

Tags: xamarin.forms

I've got following view:

```
<ContentPage.Content>

    <AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

        <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="20, 0, 20, 0">

                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="Login" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                    <Entry Text="{Binding Login, Mode=OneWayToSource}"></Entry>
                </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="Hasło" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                    <Entry IsPassword="True" Text="{Binding Password, Mode=TwoWay}"></Entry>
                </StackLayout>

                <Button Text="Zaloguj się" Command="{Binding SignInCommand}"></Button>

            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>

        <BoxView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" BackgroundColor="Gray" Opacity="0.5" InputTransparent="false" IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}" />
        <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

    </AbsoluteLayout>

</ContentPage.Content>
```

I want to move BoxView and ActivityIndicator to external control to make reusable component. The problem is that to achieve this I need to "group" these controls to obtain one child element.

The question is if is there any element I can use to group my controls, but which will not affect the way how controls are displayed? Alternatevlly which element I can use and how to still have effect of overlay over whole page and loading indicator?

I was trying to use AbsoluteLayout, StackLayout etc. but I couldn't position it to persist initial effect (overlay on whole page and loading indicator in the center with opacity = 1).

Comment: So, you want to do a overlay in every page? Try to be a little more clear and specific

Comment: That's right. I don't want to copy and pase BoxView and ActivityIndicator in each page, but to make component/control with these elements and use this component on the pages where I need to show loading indicator for the user.

Comment: Here is a Creating a ControlTemplate official doc can be used for reference.(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/control-templates/creating).

Answer (score 0):

You can use DependencyService and reuse it in any page.

Check [this tutorial](https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2018/03/19/build-yo-own-awesome-activity-loading-indicator-page-for-xamarin-forms/).

There is also a [working sample](https://github.com/UdaraAlwis/Xamarin-Playground/tree/master/XFLoadingPageService).